# error executing sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error using this query

```
select dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed,
     Verdict, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'PASS') AS PASS, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'FAIL') AS FAIL, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'INCONC') AS INCONC, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'TIMEOUT') AS TIMEOUT 
from results 
where BuildID = 'Beta1'       
group by TestCase,dbresultsid 
order by Analyzed
```

It says

> Column 'results.BuildID' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.'

The same query runs fine in MYSQL. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: @ck : thank you for beautifying my SQL code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to aggregate your BuildID and Analyzed columns or add them to the group by.
Also note that the way you're doing it now is horribly inefficient.

Take a look [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/04/Back-to-Basics-Count-Count-Count-Sum-or-how-to.aspx) how you can improve your performance by doing only one table scan instead 
of several hundred you're going to have

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I recently moved from MYSQL to MSSQL and the link you provided was very useful.

Comment: can you please look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809225/difference-in-these-queries

Answer (score 1):

If you use Group By in your query, you must add all columns that aren't aggregate functions to your Group By clause. So add BuildID to the Group By clause and all other columns without aggregates (like Verdict, etc.), and it will work.

Also see the [GROUP BY documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) for further details.

Comment: why do I need to add all the columns to the group by or order by? is this the way MSSQL server designed? I do not need to add like this in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. In MSSQL you *have to* do this, as in MySQL you don't need to.

Comment: can you please look here please 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809225/difference-in-these-queries

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to be this:

```
select dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed,
     Verdict, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'PASS') AS PASS, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'FAIL') AS FAIL, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'INCONC') AS INCONC, 
     (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
             and Verdict = 'TIMEOUT') AS TIMEOUT 
from results 
where BuildID = 'Beta1'       
group by TestCase,dbresultsid, BuildID, Analyzed
order by Analyzed
```

Whilst you are filtering BuildID to only be one value, SQL Server requires that it be specified in the group by list.

Answer (score 0):

Group By Clause in SQL Server allows columns which are in Group By Clause and in case we want some other columns then we need to access them via Aggregate functions like MAX, MIN etc.

Answer (score 0):

Group by means - group the results by listed fields, and execute some aggregate function (sum,avg...) on the rest of the fields. Everything that does not have count() or avg() or sum() must be in group by.

However, it looks like you mixed two different queries together. If you need a number of records with each verdict for a given BuildId, the query is simply:

```
select BuildID, Verdict, count(*)
group by BuildID, Verdict
```

If that's not what you want, you should describe what you are trying to achieve