# difference in these queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am executing a query different way in MSSQL, but the second query is not giving result as the first one.

```
Query 1:
    select dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed,
         Verdict, 
         (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
                 and Verdict = 'PASS') AS PASS, 
         (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
                 and Verdict = 'FAIL') AS FAIL, 
         (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
                 and Verdict = 'INCONC') AS INCONC, 
         (select count(Verdict) from results where BuildID = 'Beta1' 
                 and Verdict = 'TIMEOUT') AS TIMEOUT 
    from results 
    where BuildID = 'Beta1'       
    group by TestCase,dbresultsid 
    order by Analyzed

Query 2:

select dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed,
         Verdict, 
(case when Verdict='PASS' then count(Verdict) else 0 end) as PASS,
(case when Verdict='FAIL' then count(Verdict) else 0 end) as FAIL,
(case when Verdict='INCONC' then count(Verdict) else 0 end) as INCONC,
(case when Verdict='TIMEOUT' then count(Verdict) else 0 end) as TIMEOUT
from results
where 
BuildID = 'Beta1'
group by TestCase,dbresultsid 
order by Analyzed


Results :
for Query 1:
if the total number of PASS = 20,
 then PASS column will display 20 everywhere.

Results :
for Query 2:
here whereever there is PASS, it displays 1 and the total 20 rows where pass is displayed there is 1,
```

I want the results of query 2 to be same as query 1

any ideas please?

thanks,

Comment: I recomment you use "group by dbresuultid, TestCase" not group by "dbresuultid, TestCase" if dbresultid is key.
query will executed effectly.

Comment: The order of the group by makes no difference at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query does a SELECT with a WHERE to return only the rows that have a matching verdict and then counts those rows. The second query counts all rows every time.

You might try:

```
select 
  dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed, Verdict, 
  Sum(case when Verdict='PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as PASS,
  Sum(case when Verdict='FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as FAIL,
  Sum(case when Verdict='INCONC' then 1 else 0 end) as INCONC,
  Sum(case when Verdict='TIMEOUT' then 1 else 0 end) as TIMEOUT
from 
  results
where 
  BuildID = 'Beta1'
group by 
  TestCase, dbresultsid 
order by 
  Analyzed
```

Test data:

```
  CREATE TABLE #Test (BuildID Integer, Verdict char(7))
  INSERT INTO #TEST (Buildid, Verdict)
    VALUES (1, 'PASS')
  INSERT INTO #TEST (Buildid, Verdict)
    VALUES (1, 'PASS')
  INSERT INTO #TEST (BuildID, Verdict)
    VALUES (2, 'FAIL')
  INSERT INTO #TEST (BuildID, Verdict)
    VALUES (3, 'INCONC')
  INSERT INTO #TEST (BuildID, Verdict)
    VALUES(4, 'TIMEOUT')
```

Query:

```
select buildid,
  sum(case verdict when 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as Pass,
  sum(case verdict when 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as Fail,
  sum(case verdict when 'INCONC' then 1 else 0 end) as Inconc,
  sum(case verdict when 'TIMEOUT' then 1 else 0 end) as TimeOut
FROM #temp
group by buildid
```

Output:

```
Item    buildid PASS    Fail    Inconc  TimeOut 
1         1      2       0        0        0
2         2      0       1        0        0
3         3      0       0        1        0
4         4      0       0        0        1
```

Comment: but I want total PASS in every row not just 1

Comment: can you tell me which one is efficient? and how to see the execution plan in MSSQL?

Comment: I got the way to see the execution plan. But I am unable to interpret it at the moment

Comment: Undid it - didn't notice grouping. Sorry

Comment: @JPro: You get PASS every row. There can only be one Verdict per row, so you're counting it into the appropriate column (PASS, FAIL, INCONC, TIMEOUT). Each row that has a verdict of "PASS" will add a value of 1, and the SUM() (missing from my original post) will add them up. Try it.

Comment: @JPro: As far as most efficient, the one with the CASE will be. The first one makes four full selects against the data to return four separate result sets and count them, and then a fifth select to put them all together. The one with the CASE makes exactly one pass through the data.

Comment: eventhough I SUM it it displays 1 only and not the total count

Comment: It displays 1 because you are grouping by a key column.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the first one?, In my opinion is a nice way to get your results if the keys for reference and group by are well defined. I only will change the "where" in the subselects for not repeating the key each time, making a direct reference to the main table instead.

```
(select count .. from results where BuildID = r1.BuildID and Verdict  ..)
from results r1
```

Comment: someone suggested that query 1 is horrible way to do it

Comment: query 1 is a horrible way to do it.  Both of the other examples are correct and faster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you mention in comment that dbresultsid is a key column,
 Including it in the group by clause is ineffective, you will get one output row for every row in original table (that matches your where clause).

Secondly, because the subqueries in first query are ***un-correlated***, their output is not dependant on the row from the outer query. Therefore they will only be executed once, and the ***same*** generated value will be repeated in *every* outout row.

So, If the output of the first query is really what you want (where there is one row per original 'Beta1' row in results table and every row in output has the same values in the last 4 columns) then what you have is pretty close to best you can do. Just take out the group by clause - you don't need it.

```
Select 
  dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed, Verdict,  
  z.PASS, z.FAIL, z.INCONC, z.TIMEOUT
From results r Cross Join 
  (Select 
     Sum(case when Verdict='PASS' then 1 else 0 end) PASS,
     Sum(case when Verdict='FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) FAIL,
     Sum(case when Verdict='INCONC' then 1 else 0 end) INCONC,
     Sum(case when Verdict='TIMEOUT' then 1 else 0 end) TIMEOUT
   From results Where BuildID = 'Beta1') Z
Where BuildID = 'Beta1'
Order By Analyzed
```

Comment: but this query will display 1 in whereever it finds PASS, but I want total PASS count.

Comment: Query should be displaying the count of Pass rows with 'Beta1', and the same value for dbResultsId, Testcase, and Analyzed... unless, let me guess! Is dbResultsId a Key value ???

Comment: HI, but adding '(Select Count(*) From Results 
    Where BuildID = 'Beta1' And Verdict='PASS') TotalPass' is similar to Query 1, which is what I want to void scanning the table many times.

Comment: You won't be, this is an UN-correlated sub-query, it will only be executed once.

Comment: yes dbresultsid is key value, but I want this result:
PASS FAIL INCONC
20   2    4

and not 
PASS FAIL INCONC
1    0    0
0    1    0
1    0    0

Comment: Which brings me to another point... All the oputput in your first query is from uncorrelated subqueries.  They have no connection to the results table in the outer query.  SO there is actually no need to even have it. except to get the values of the firts 5 columns (dbresultsid, TestCase, BuildID, Analyzed, Verdict) and the group By is doing nothing if dbresultsId is a key field...

Comment: Every row in the first query will have the same value in all the output fields from the uncorrelated sub queries. i.e., it will not be dependant on the data in that individual row.  Why do you want this data repeated for every row in the output?

Comment: so that I can take that value just once and display it to user as total PASS. I need not count how many 1's are there for each PASS

Comment: If the output of the first query is really what you want (where there is one row per original 'Beta1' row in results table and every row in output has the same values in the last 4 columns) then what you have is pretty close to best you can do.  Just take out the group by clause - you don't need it.

Comment: if I take out the group by, MSSQL gives an error that table.field is invalid because it is not contained in either aggregate or Groupby clause for all the fields

Comment: The group by in your first query??  It is not required. There is nop aggregate function in the outer query in your first query.. The inner subqueries son't need a group By.  In any event,  please try the newly edited query in my answer above.

Comment: JPro: your comments show me that you don't quite appreciate how the SQL Server Optimiser works.  Where you Think there are multiple scans, there are not.  SQL Query != Execution Plan.  The oprimiser is cleverer that you give it credit for...  The uncorrelated sub query should work perfectly fine.